# From custom directive on an input how can I invalidate the parent form?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have made a custom directive to do input validation, now the directive works fine in most cases but the way I have done it is to invalidate the field before I inspect it with `ctrl.$setValidity('validation', false);` and then I validate the field change it's `$setValidity` to `true` if it's valid. But my problem is when I use `onBlur` event inside my directive, because I invalidate the field as soon as I start typing it becomes dirty and shows invalid even though I just want it invalid after the `onBlur`, so I found out that the best is to invalidate the Form instead of each fields.

So to make it short how can I find the parent form of the input element and set it to invalidate?

When knowing the form name, I know I can do this `scope.myFormName.$setValidity('validation', false);` and it works, but I am trying to be generic and find the form object by myself and then invalidate it. I am trying to loop with the `elm.parent()` but not much success yet...and I'm trying to stay as generic as possible so with jqLite.

**EDIT**
I got some code working but it's not exactly clean code, does anyone have a better way?

```
var j = 0;
var parentElm = elm.parent();
var parentFormElm = null;
do {
  if(parentElm.prop('tagName').toUpperCase() === "FORM") {
    parentFormElm = parentElm;
    break;
  }      
  parentElm = parentElm.parent(); // next parent
}while(parentElm !== "form" && j++ < 50);

scope[parentFormElm.prop('name')].$setValidity('validation', false);
```

Comment: If you just want the field to become invalid after `onBlur` gets triggered, why don't you validate it when that event occurs?

Comment: Because if I don't invalidate the form and I'm using `onBlur` the form shows up valid when I start and my submit button is enable which is of course wrong fact...

Comment: So you want the form to be invalid as soon as the user starts typing but you want the input itself to become invalid only after it loses focus?

Comment: Not exactly, I would rather have the form to be invalid at first without even invalidating the inputs yet (since they're still untouched).

Comment: The problem is that if I invalidate the field instead of the form, as soon as I start typing the CSS kicks in and my field becomes red and then when I blur out then I get my validation to be displayed as I want yes but the CSS is annoying while I type.

Comment: You can try my Github project and you'll see what I mean, on the first input it's onBlur but even though as soon as you start typing it's becoming red, why? Well because I invalidated the field it's no more pristine and the CSS kicks in, if I don't invalidate it at first and only after the onBlur then the CSS doesn't kick in... See my Github https://github.com/ghiscoding/angular-validation  just download it and run it, nothing to install

Comment: If it's just a matter of styling things (and IE8 support isn't required) I guess you could have different CSS classes for each possible state: `.ng-invalid:focus` and `.ng-invalid:not(:focus)`.

Comment: Good point, thanks Michael I will indeed look at that.

Comment: I ended up using your CSS code, if you turn it into an answer (understandable for other users too), I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's just a matter of styling things (as pointed out in the comments) you can just tweak Angular's CSS classes so the input field gets highlighted only when it's not focused:

```
.ng-invalid.ng-dirty:not(:focus) {
  background-color: #ff7373;
}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/v5WPY6ozj65oTgL44jWe?p=preview)

If you can't afford to use CSS3 selectors, then you'll need two CSS classes:

```
.ng-invalid.ng-dirty {
  background-color: #ff7373;
}

.ng-invalid.ng-dirty:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/s8TilL3cZVpX3pZYK9XY?p=preview)

Comment: Perfect that worked, great to know CSS3 and alternative as well.. Thanks again